# Slack API scope to check how many people viewed a post in a channel (message activity)

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to gather message activity information about messages in a channel via slack API.
I know this is possible in slack itself:
https://slack.com/help/articles/360046708113-View-message-activity

I assume there is a scope (probably an admin scope) which can return the same information, but I could not find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Slack API methods do not retrieve the analytics data you're looking for. The [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) could be a relevant endpoint, but this does not include views engagement information.

The alternative is the [one](https://slack.com/help/articles/360046708113-View-message-activity) you mentioned above.

Comment: thanks, but I need this data for a dashboard I am working on, so I cant really use the slack app separately for this. Do you know how slack measures this? I mean there is got to be a backend for the message activity panel. I am ok to use other api endpoints to calculate this data the same way slack does.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).